# JQuery Dialog - adding and ID to the default close a-link ("X" icon)

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium

Is there any way to force JQuery to add an id to the default close "X" a-link widget (top right of the dialog window on the header bar) when you instantiate the dialog?

I know that you can give an ID to the OK/Cancel buttons when you define them in the options during dialog instantiation, although this is not an officially listed param.  Was just wondering if there was a similar, unofficial param you could use for setting the id on the dialog close link?

This is required as currently, when using the Selenium FF plugin to record test scripts, it uses some ropey XPath to identify the close click, which is no good if your page structure has dynamically included/excluded elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can search the button by its title

```
webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@title='close']"))
```